# Does windows sdk have any feature similar to linux-style mount-points and virtual folder/files?

Tags: windows

I know windows certainty did not *use* to have anything like mount points, other than symbolic link directories, but those still must point to a real folder with real files in it. And I haven't found any evidence yet that it does now, so maybe all I'm looking for here is confirmation that it really and truly still does not.

What I mean by mount-points and virtual folder/files is how it is possible to use OS-SDK filesystem calls (on some platforms) to expose a virtual folder containing virtual files, by implementing some interface with methods for enumerating things and hooking it in to the filesystem.

Actually I believe windows does have an api for mounting "drives" like this. Which for example I assume is how drivers for a thumbdrive or your phone works. But I actually need/want to mount as a named folder, within a real drive.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/cloudmirror-sample/